# iPhone camera landscape orientation issue

Tags: ios, camera

I have scenario in which the camera is to be forced to be in landscape when ever you want click . I tried various things but i am not able to make it landscape . In one forum i even read that doing so may lead to app rejection . Is it so? if not can someone give me the solution for the same ?

Comment: App is in potrait mode and when ever i click on camera i want it to open in landscape

Comment: It has to be presented in landscape mode only , as the app is in potrait mode but when the camera is opened i want it to be presented in the landscape mode , dont want image to be captured in portrait mode .

Answer (score 0):

Which model of the iphone are you using? Do you by chance have the rotation lock enabled? Is this a third party app or the official iphone camera app? sometimes if you use a third party app, they don't always work correctly with rotation settings.

Comment: i am making an app, no the rotation is not locked  .

Comment: Its possible you need to adjust zoom settings or even more rare make sure nothing else is running in the background. If you are using xcode, check your deployment settings to make sure both orientations are enabled

Comment: Hey i have got the solution for same, have posted it . Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Hey i found one solution for the same through which we can give an impression to user that camera is presented in landscape mode and user will take image in landscape . We need to add a custom view (a bar giving an impression that its a landscape view) on the camera with button having click functionality hiding the default controllers of camera . See attached screenshot . [Output of solution i found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPfXr.jpg)

Comment: It would have helped if some of that information had been in the question.

Comment: Thanks zaph , will keep you busy with more questions , do you have a better solution , or this one is fine .

Comment: The solution seems to be an overlay so the user is promted to hold the camera in landscape. There are two ways to do that, AVCapture and a Camera Overlay, the latter is easier and probably will fill your needs. Googe, there are sample projects for both.